# Can I use a Thunderbolt cable to connect an iPad to a MacBook Air as second display?

Tags: thunderbolt, ipad

Is it possible to use a Thunderbolt to Thunderbolt cable to connect a new-generation iPad with a new-generation MacBook Air so that the iPad can be used as a 2nd monitor?

Comment: iPad doesn't have a thunderbolt port, to my knowledge, so no.

Answer (score 2):

No, the iPad doesn't have thunderbolt, nor the capacity to function as a screen for another device by any cable.

You could use your iPad as an external display over the network though (remember your Macbook can create a network if you don't have one), there are quite a few apps that do this,

Answer (score 1):

The app [Duet Display](http://www.duetdisplay.com/) allows you to use any iOS device as an external display and your Mac is running at least OS 10.9. The connection happens entirely over the 30-pin or Lightning cable which might make it lag less than a wifi solution. It's [available on the app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/duet-display/id935754064).

Comment: Do note that the reviews all note that the app is quite buggy.